pythonservice.exe crash when run a python script as win10 service after upgrade python version from 3.10 to 3.12. Cannot find the reason
I write a python script used to reversely forward a port. I use pywin32 to convert the python codes as a win10 service. The service runs ok when python version is 3.10. However, after I upgrade the python from version 3.10 to 3.12, The service stop immediatly everytime I start it. I don't know why. Can anyone give some suggestions? Thanks a lot. The following is my python codes:
import time
import sys
import subprocess as sp

import win32serviceutil  # ServiceFramework and commandline helper
import win32service  # Events
import servicemanager  # Simple setup and logging

class MyService:
    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        rport=55009
        cmd=f'ssh  -fNR {rport}:127.0.0.1:3389 username@remotehost -p 22'
        cmd1='ssh -tt  username@remotehost -p 22  \"netstat -tpa | grep \'**:{} **\'\"'.format(rport)
        while True:
            a=sp.run(cmd1,capture_output=True,shell=True).stdout.decode("utf-8") 
            # print('one turn')
            if f":{rport}" not in a:
                try:
                    p=sp.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
                    p.wait(2)
                except sp.TimeoutExpired:
                    p.kill()
                except:
                    print('execution failed')
            elif not "ESTABLISHED" in a:
                cmd2="\"ps aux | grep '**xiaoya**'| awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill\""
                cmd2="ssh -tt  username@remotehost -p 22 "+cmd2
                try: 
                    a=sp.run(cmd2,shell=True)
                    p=sp.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
                    p.wait(2)
                except sp.TimeoutExpired:
                    p.kill()
                except:
                    print('execution failed')
            time.sleep(5*1)
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Service running...")


class MyServiceFramework(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'autossh1'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'autossh1'

    def SvcStop(self):
    
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.service_impl.stop()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        self.service_impl = MyService()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        # Run the service
        self.service_impl.run()


def init():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(MyServiceFramework)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyServiceFramework)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()


Why did you upgrade then? Do you need to use a feature introduced in Python 3.11 or 3.12 that forces you to upgrade?

Because I want to install the service to another new computer, But the python website doesn't provide the version 3.10 installer. By the way, I have tested the codes with python 3.11. It works fine now. Thanks anyway.

The Python website doesnt provide version 3.10? Really? Because all python versions are available in the python website

Oh, I only check  python 3.10.14. Python 3.10.14 only provides the souce code. But python 3.10.11 still provides the binary installer.

This appears to be a bug with LogInfoMsg and Python 3.12.
As a workaround, try LogMsg with the info type:
servicemanager.LogMsg( servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0xF000, ( "Service running...", "" ) )

